# How to make a sheet that is partially shown when not presented in SwiftUI? (like the one in the Shortcuts app)

Tags: ios, swiftui

While many UI-elements are easy to create in SwiftUI, there´s one I'm struggling with. I don't know what it's called, but I'm talking about the bottom-search bar which turns into a full-blown sheet akin to the one shown when calling `.sheet(isPresented:)` when dragged up.

Here's a visual:
[image]
Screencap of the mentioned UI-element in the Shortcuts app

I realize there's a good chance this isn't possible yet, but I thought asking was worth the shot :)

Comment: That wasn't “possible” using UIKit and isn't “possible” using SwiftUI, in the sense that neither framework provides it as an easy built-in widget. It was implemented using custom views in UIKit and you'll need to implement it using custom views in SwiftUI.